# Labeling variables after recoding them

Tags: stata

I would like to label the variables back to their original variable labels after I `recode` them in Stata. How can I accomplish this?

```
sysuse auto, clear
recode foreign (1=2 "Foreign") (0=1 "Domestic"), gen(foreign1)
drop foreign
rename foreign1 foreign


* label var foreign "Car type"


foreach var of varlist foreign {
local var_label: var label `var'
local var_label1: regexm("`var_label'", "\((.)+\)")
label var `var' "`var_label1'"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with `regexm()` looks awkward to me, which is presumably part of the question.

1. In your example, there is a simple alternative that leaves the variable label intact:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
replace foreign = 1 + foreign
label def origin 1 Domestic 2 Foreign, modify

. d foreign

Variable      Storage   Display    Value
    name         type    format    label      Variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foreign         byte    %8.0g      origin     Car origin
```

2. This works too:

```
sysuse auto, clear

recode foreign (1=2 "Foreign") (0=1 "Domestic"), gen(foreign1)
_crcslbl foreign1 foreign 
drop foreign 
rename foreign1 foreign 

d foreign
```

3. You are aware of the scope for saving the variable label as a local macro for safe-keeping.

(In general, 0-1 indicator variables are immensely more useful and natural statistically than 1-2 indicators, but I presume that you are just making up a reproducible example. If in doubt see e.g. https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099 )